# Chosen as the deadlock victim on simple Add() -> SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ssms

This simple program

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Parallel.For(0, 1000000, InsertTestEntity);
}

private static void InsertTestEntity(int i)
{
    using (var dbContext = new TestDbContext())
    {
        dbContext.TestEntities.Add(new TestEntity { HugeString = "Baby shark," + string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Repeat("doo", 500)) });
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class TestEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string HugeString { get; set; }
}

public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TestEntity> TestEntities { get; set; }
}
```

Throws an exception like

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at EntityFrameworkStressTest.Program.InsertTestEntity(Int32 i) in c:\Git\EntityFrameworkStressTest\EntityFrameworkStressTest\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()

Inner Exception 1:
UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Inner Exception 2:
SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 100) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

The SQL table looks like this in SSMS

[image: TestEntities table from SSMS]

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520639/entity-framework-deadlock-problem, but that question was poorly documented (and not easily found before the solution was known).

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the SSMS screenshot, there seem to be no indication of a primary key.  There should have been a key symbol next to the ID column.

[image: Some ID actually declared as primary key]

Further inspection reveals that Id is indeed declared as identity (SQL Server for `AUTO INCREMENT`), but not as primary key.  To make `Id` a real primary key right click the table in SSMS and choose Design, right click the `Id` row in the column designer and click SET PRIMARY KEY:

[image]

After this, the stress tests runs without deadlocking itself.